# Javascript is telling me a node has 23 children, but it only has 11 and firebug agrees with me

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick

Im working on a HTML test page with a simple grid that has red or blue squares. If you click a red square it should be blue, if you click a blue square it should change to red. Sounds easy.

I have it set up so there are rows with id's r + rownum. In my testfile i just have 2 rows: r1 and r2. Each row has the same number of children (right now 11). But when I do this:

```
var row = document.getElementById("r1");
alert("child count: " + row.childNodes.length);
```

I get 23. I get 23 for both rows. This is causing problems where wrong box gets its background changed and sometimes nothing changes. I'll post my html and javascript, its pretty straightforward.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
      div.permissiongrid { width: 780px; }
      div.row { display: block; width: 780px; }
      span.type { width: 55px; padding: 5px; height: 55px; display: block; float: left; border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000; }
      span.yes { background: red; }
      span.no { background: blue; }
      span.leftborder { border-left: 1px solid #000000; }
      span.num { text-indent: 1.5em; line-height: 4em; }
      p { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function change(rownum, field)
      {
          var row = document.getElementById("r" + rownum);
          var box = row.childNodes[field];
          alert("clicked inside element with id: r" + rownum + " has child count: " + row.childNodes.length);
          if(box.className == "type no")
             box.className = "type yes";
          else
             box.className = "type no";
      }
    </script>
    <title>grid test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="permissiongrid">
        <div class="row">
          <span class="type leftborder">Level</span>
          <span class="type">Edit Permiss-<br />ions</span>
          <span class="type">Create Accout</span>
          <span class="type">Edit Account</span>
          <span class="type">Delete Account</span>
          <span class="type">Create Page</span>
          <span class="type">Edit Page</span>
          <span class="type">Delete Page</span>
          <span class="type">Create Category</span>
          <span class="type">Edit Category</span>
          <span class="type">Delete Category</span>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="r1">
          <span class="type leftborder num">0</span>
          <span class="type no" onclick="change(1, 1)">a</span>
          <span class="type yes" onclick="change(1, 2)">b</span>
          <span class="type yes" onclick="change(1, 3)">c</span>
          <span class="type yes" onclick="change(1, 4)">d</span>
          <span class="type yes" onclick="change(1, 5)">e</span>
          <span class="type yes" onclick="change(1, 6)">f</span>
          <span class="type yes" onclick="change(1, 7)">g</span>
          <span class="type yes" onclick="change(1, 8)">h</span>
          <span class="type yes" onclick="change(1, 9)">i</span>
          <span class="type yes" onclick="change(1, 10)">j</span>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="r2">
          <span class="type leftborder num">1</span>
          <span class="type no" onclick="change(2, 1)">a</span>
          <span class="type no" onclick="change(2, 2)">b</span>
          <span class="type no" onclick="change(2, 3)">c</span>
          <span class="type no" onclick="change(2, 4)">d</span>
          <span class="type no" onclick="change(2, 5)">e</span>
          <span class="type no" onclick="change(2, 6)">f</span>
          <span class="type no" onclick="change(2, 7)">g</span>
          <span class="type no" onclick="change(2, 8)">h</span>
          <span class="type no" onclick="change(2, 9)">i</span>
          <span class="type no" onclick="change(2, 10)">j</span>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whitespace is also a `childNode`. You'll have to check `nodeType`

Rather than fetching all `childNodes`, you want to do `row.getElementsByTagName('span')`

Comment: never knew that, i change it and that works. the moar you know

Answer (score 1):

Text nodes are included in `.childNodes`. There are 10 text nodes between your 11 `<span>` elements, 1 text node before, and 1 text node after. Your 11 `<span>`s plus the 12 text nodes results in 23 nodes. You can use the `.nodeType` property to determine the type of node or use `row.getElementsByTagName('span')` instead.